# Automatically update model relationship after saving to the DB

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have the following two Django models `A` and `B`:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey('A', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I would like to instantiate both of them and then save them to the DB in the following way:

```
# Code sample 1
a = A()
b = B()
b.a = a
# Do something with b.a, e.g. b.a.some_method()
a.save()
b.save()
```

Although `a` has been saved to the DB before `b` and therefore already has an ID, `b.save()` will fail with an `IntegrityError`:

```
IntegrityError: null value in column "a_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null).
```

As a "workaround", it is possible to re-assign `a` to `b` before calling `b.save()`:

```
# Code sample 2
a = A()
b = B()
b.a = a
# Do something with b.a, e.g. b.a.some_method()
a.save()
b.a = a
b.save()
```

This works but it seems redundant having to assign `a` to `b` twice. It feels like `b` should know about `a` having changed or having been saved to the DB. Is there a way to make code sample 1 work?

Comment: When you set `b.a = ...`, it *immediately* fetches the `id`, and assigns that id to `b.a_id`. It might indeed have been a better idea to do this "lazily", but this can also result in some edge-cases with "strange" semantics.

Comment: "Lot's" of code rely on being able to find `b.a_id` whenever there is a `b.a` (e.g. when you just need the pk and not the entire object) -- django didn't always have `prefetch_related`...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to assign a to b twice. Try this instead:

```
a = A()
a.save()

b = B()
b.a = a
b.save()
```

This will work because Model object primary key will only be assigned when save() is called. When assigning foreign keys, the primary key is used by default.